# SonarQube includes test classes in coverage

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

I use Sonarqube for my current JAVA / Spring Boot2 project. 
I recognized that Sonarqube fails to measure the correct coverage, because it reports that my tests themselves are not covered by tests. 
I am using a Jenkinsfile and I use a different naming convention for tests:

Instead of using the naming schema "ClassNameTest" with suffix Test, I use:

- ClassNameUT for unit tests
- ClassNameIT for integration tests
- ClassNameAT for acceptance tests
- ClassNameMT for manually started tests

This may be part of the problem.

How can I fix it?